# Meteor - Template.currentData() not reactive?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze

In one of my templates I use [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) to change some DOM elements when the data context changes, but it never gets triggered.

```
Template.onRendered(function () {
  this.autorun(function () {
    var someData = Template.currentData().someData;
    // some DOM manipulation
  }
}
```

The documentation states that [Template.currentData()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata):

> Establishes a reactive dependency on the result.

So if `someData` is being changed, it should trigger a recomputation, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research and getting a better understanding of [reactive data sources and reactive computations](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/) and the underlying [Tracker and Autorun](http://manual.meteor.com/#tracker) I figured out, that I just needed to change

```
var someData = Template.currentData().someData;
```

to

```
var currentData = Template.currentData();
var someData = currentData.someData;
```

So it seems that only `Template.currentData()` is a reactive data source, but **the properties of the object it returns are not**.

One could probably change that using [reactive-var](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg).

Comment: I am not sure there is a different here. Those two lines of code are equivilant to the first one. Once you activated `Template.currentData()` you already registered a reactive dependency in the autorun context. The autorun was supposed to be called without this change.